# EPS file loses quality after converting the docx file to pdf

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, eps

I opened a PDF file in gimp with a 600 dpi resolution. Then I saved the file in EPS format and then inserted the EPS file in a word document with the DOCX format.

Problem is when I convert the DOCX file to a new PDF file, I see that the quality of the EPS file drops! Obviously the output figure (in the PDF file) doesn't look like a 600 dpi figure as I saved in the gimp.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Does the EPS you inserted look OK when you close and reopen the DOCX?

Comment: yes, there are big differences between docx and pdf in 400% zoom

Comment: What OS are you using? There are command line tools for pdf to eps conversion in *nix that might give better results.